# Single node CDH 5 installation using Cloudera Manager

Tags: cloudera-cdh

I have single node server and I want to install CDH5 on top of it. Can I use Cloudera Manager to install CDH5 on the same node on which CM is running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but be sure to: 1) use a supported OS, and 2) install the Oracle JDK first.

See: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_qs_prereq.html

Note also: depending on your needs here, may be easier to install the [QuickStart VM](http://www.cloudera.com/quickstartvm), which is a single-node cluster + guest OS and other goodies.